# How to create different clickable parts from the gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I want to create a gameobject which is clickable on 2 different ways.
[image]

This picture is just an example but this is what I want. There are two different clickable "hitpoints" which have different functions. The first(black one) should move the gameobject on the x- and y-coordinates. The yellow part should change the angle of the gameobject. I allready tried some things with raycast but I didn't get it. Do someone have a good example maybe? Would be nice...

Greets
Sander

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple colliders in the same game object, and change their Center and Size properties to position them correctly. I think this is the simplest way.

Than you use the hook `OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)` like this example:

```
public class CollisionHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    private IDictionary<Collider, string> colliders;
    void Start () {
        int i = 0;
        colliders = new Dictionary<Collider, string>();

        foreach (var collider in GetComponents<Collider>())
            colliders.Add(collider, "collider_" + i++);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log(colliders[collision.contacts[0].thisCollider]);
    }
}
```

I similar approach would be having 2 empty game objects as children of your game object; they would only have one collider each, and a script to handle the collision.

Comment: Thought about it but it makes no sense. You can't request which collider got a click.If you have 2 Collider on the object the OnCollisionEnter will work for both colliders. Already checked it...

Comment: That's not true. I updated my answer with code telling how you can achieve this. I tested and it works.